# Timepicker not showing time on a single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have two input boxes one is for selecting date and another for time. I am trying to validate these two boxes based on some conditions, such that if the date is not selected, the time should not get selected.

I'm using eonasdan datetimepicker, I'm getting the desired output but not with the single click on a timepicker. Can some one help me out with this?

Here's what I have done so far:

```js
function starttime(){
  $('#starttime').datetimepicker({
    format: 'HH:mm',
    minDate: new Date()
  });
}
           
$('.start_time_addon').on('click keyup',function(){
  var x = $('#start').val();
  if (x == '') {
    alert('please select startdate first');
    return false;
  }
  else{
    starttime();
  }
});
        
var datePickerSix= $('.datetimepicker6');
$(datePickerSix).datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  minDate: new Date()
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Start Date</label><br>
      <div class='input-group date datetimepicker6'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id="start" name="date_end" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="start_time" class="col-form-label">Start Time</label>
          <div class='input-group date start_time_addon' id='starttime'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="HH : MM" id="Start_Time" required />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you initialize the time picker only after a click on it, so on the first click the datetimepicker is not already built. Move `starttime` initialization from `starttime` to `document.ready`.

I suggest to disable `starttime` datetimepicker when the user can not select hours. You can use [`disable()`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#disable) and [`enable()`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#enable) method of the datetimepicker.

Use [`date()`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) method to get datetimepicker selected date and you can listen to [`dp.change`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange) event to known when the user selects a date.

Here a complete example:

```js
$('#startdate').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  minDate: new Date()
}).on('dp.change', function(e){
  if( e.date ){
    // Enable timepicker only if date is selected
    $('#starttime').data("DateTimePicker").enable();
  } else {
    $('#starttime').data("DateTimePicker").disable();
  }
});

$('#starttime').datetimepicker({
  format: 'HH:mm',
  minDate: new Date(),
  useCurrent: false
});
// Disable time picker
$('#starttime').data("DateTimePicker").disable();
           
$('.start_time_addon').on('click keyup',function(){
  var x = $('#startdate').data("DateTimePicker").date();
  if ( !x ) {
    alert('please select startdate first');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Start Date</label><br>
      <div class='input-group date datetimepicker6' id="startdate">
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id="start" name="date_end" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="start_time" class="col-form-label">Start Time</label>
          <div class='input-group date start_time_addon' id='starttime'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="HH : MM" id="Start_Time" required />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've added [`useCurrent: false`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent) option to timepicker to prevent getting current time.